# Get the next instance of recurring events with the Google Calendar API v3

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get the events in my calendar over a date range (single or recurring events alike).  Now I will not necessarily know the exact datetime for the next instance of a recurring event as . 
For recurring events I want the date of the next occurrence rather than the date of the first instance as I am getting with the request below. How do I do this?

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarid}/events?fields=items(id,summary,start)&key={APIkey}&timeMax={enddate}&timeMin={startdate}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add in the URL parameter `singleEvents=True`. This will expand all recurring events into their individual items. There isn't any way to specifically get just the second event in a series if you don't already know when it is, but using that parameter will let you parse out all instances and get the one you want.

Source: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Answer (score 0):

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

Uri.Builder eventsUriBuilder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MIN_VALUE);
ContentUris.appendId(eventsUriBuilder, Long.MAX_VALUE);
String[] projection = new String[]{CalendarContract.Instances.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Instances.TITLE,
        CalendarContract.Instances.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN,
        CalendarContract.Instances.END, CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_LOCATION,
        CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID};

Uri eventsUri = eventsUriBuilder.build();
Cursor instance_cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(
        eventsUri, projection, CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN + " >= " + now + " and " + CalendarContract.Instances.BEGIN
                + " <= " + (now + 2592000000L) + " and " + CalendarContract.Instances.VISIBLE + " = 1",
        null, CalendarContract.Instances.DTSTART + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now direct way of doing that but you can hack together a method to accomplish that.

The idea is that you can specify time boundaries and limit the number of records and that's enough to do the job.

So setting the `timeMin` to now (or right after your reference event end date), `timeMax` to a big enough number, like a year from timeMin and `maxResults` = 1 will get the next instance if it exists.

Here is how this can be done in nodejs:

```
    let startDate = startTime ? new Date(startTime) : new Date()
    let endDate = endTime ? new Date(endTime) : new Date(startDate.getTime() + 12 * 31 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) // 1 year ahead
    let startDateISO = startDate.toISOString()
    let endDateISO = endDate.toISOString()

    let result = await  calendar.events.instances({
        calendarId: "primary",
        eventId: masterEventId,
        maxResults: 1,
        timeMin: startDateISO,
        timeMax: endDateISO,
        orderBy: "startTime",
        timeZone: "UTC"
    })
    let nextInstance = result.data.items[0]
```

Similarly you can get previous instance if you order results in descending order and reverse the time boundaries (set `timeMin` to a year back and `timeMax` before the start of the reference event).